# How to capture optional data (php)

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

I have a string:

```
produits/mousse-de-montage/marque/pbb/item/promax-pro-expansion
```

Everything that goes after `produits` is optional and must be captured by groups, here is my regex

```
/^.*produits(.*)?(\/marque\/.*)?(\/item\/.*)?/g
```

For some strange reason,  he put those 3 groups into a single one. If i remove question mark, he will split in 3 groups.

Comment: It is not a strange reason, the `.*` eats up everything and the question marks make two thirds of your string optional. Simply split on `/` and you should be fine here.

Comment: @Jan but as i said, those are optional and might not be present. If i remove question mark, he will split in 3 groups.

Comment: Try [`^.*?produits(.*?)(\/marque\/.*?)?(\/item\/.*?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/3YRiuc/1).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks, works perfectly.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Final regex ^.*?produits(.*?|)((?:\/marque\/)(.*?)|)?((?:\/item\/)(.*?)|)?$ to keep 3 groups and exlude marque and item